# MS Access stores the date as 30/12/1899 and not the actual date

Tags: ms-access, vba

whenever I am pushing the data from VBA code to an Access table the date field is stored as 30/12/1899 and not the actual date ? I tried formatting the date to mm/dd/yyyy before writing to the table but no success. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Show the code you are using to pass date.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA you need to use US date format AND surround the date with # signs so today would be

```
#02/20/2015#
```